# Custom pictures and music in The Sims 3 & The Sims 4

Tags: the-sims-3, the-sims-4

Is it possible to put a custom pictures in the Sims 3 and Sims 4 ?

Also in Sims 3 you can put custom music in the game, can the same be done in Sims 4 ?

Comment: By custom pictures, do you mean like custom paintings?

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to find anything on putting in 'custom pictures', but I was able to find how to add custom music.

You can add custom music to all the sims games (as outlined [here](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Game_guide:Adding_custom_music)) but sinced you asked for just The [Sims 3](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Game_guide:Adding_custom_music#The_Sims_3) and The [Sims 4](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Game_guide:Adding_custom_music#The_Sims_4) that's all that I will put here.

Just a couple of notes; when adding custom music, it just appears under radio stations and you cannot change the name of the radio station it appears under (this applies for all versions of the sims), also all the music has to be in .mp3 format.

### The Sims 3

To add music to the "Custom Music" radio station in The Sims 3:

1. Open the custom music folder (usually located under `My Documents\Electronic Arts\The Sims 3`)
2. Copy music from your desired folder (ex iTunes) and paste it to the custom music folder
3. Start The Sims 3 and select the "Custom Music" station

### The Sims 4

To copy music to a genre specific radio station in The Sims 4:

1. Open the custom music folder (usually located under `My Documents\Electronic Arts\The Sims 4`)
2. Select a folder genre that you would like to place your music into
3. Copy music from your desired folder (ex iTunes) and paste it to the custom music folder
4. Start the game and select the radio station that you put your music into. Note that the selected station will also play the default music. You can disable these tracks by going into game options, selecting music, and then click on the green checkbox to disable the tracks you don't want to be played